# android multiple sound play together by saving in sd card

Tags: android, audio, mixing

I am developing an application in which i have some instruments. Each instrument have a unique sound file. now what i want to do is if I choose four instruments then the sound of all selected instruments should play together and the mixed sound should be saved in sd card for future use. my sound files may be WAV or MP3. unable to find the way. help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: so what you have tried yet and what you are looking for .. you want to write your application by some one and post here .. you need to put your efforts too !!!

Comment: it's not the whole application that i posted it's just a part.i tried sound pool i can play .ogg files together but not playing wav or mp3 and i didn't find any way to save the mixed sound in sd card.